# How to make input with Dimensions(width, height and length) and stacking it up(useField array)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-forms

I am building a form where I'd like to create an input field that accepts three values (width, height, and length) and stacking it up using react use field array, similar to what you see in the GIF below:

[image]

btw I'm using nextjs 13

Comment: That's just three input fields...

Comment: or you can use ui component library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably best achieved if you encapsulate three separate `text` input HTML fields within something like a `div` and add the styling necessary with some CSS.
There is no such input that can do the above out of the box.
You will need to retrieve the data from all three inputs separately and handle them accordingly.